# Download file from IIS 7 via HTTPS using PHP

Tags: php, c++, https, iis-7

Sorry for my English. We are developing an application for the terminals (in C ++). We have come to a stage where we realize the terminal update. We have an IIS 7 Web server and set it in PHP. We use HTTPS channel to improve safety.

Our task for the implementation of:

1. On the server, we need to convert binary to HEX
2. Download the HEX file to the terminal.
3. On the terminal, we need to convert back to the HEX file and upgrade.

We can not directly download a binary file from the server. For example via FTP or FTPS. We can only use the HTTPS protocol.

All information supplied will be converted to HEX. If we directly send to the terminal a binary file (for example, through a PHP function echo), there will be a string in the file type NULL, and the application stops to read the file further.
There is our code in server:

```
<?php
$buffer = file_get_contents("HW.bin");
$buffer1 = bin2hex($buffer);
print($buffer);
?>
```

The problem is that during file upload failure happens and we have to download the file knitted.

Question:

1. What is the size of the TCP-IP packet? In general, there is a sense of touch? If so, how? (Server IIS7)
2. How to implement download the continuation? For example, I downloaded the file to 50% and then I want to continue the download fails.
3. What and where are we wrong to use?
4. As a professional, as you would do in this situation?

All questions refer only to the server. By this I do not put code from the terminal. There's all we can do to control. But we are happy to read your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you download the binary file?

Comment: Function in the terminal fails. We thought that this is due to the size of TCP packets

Comment: Ah, ok. Could it be that it doesn't have access to the bin file server side? If you just navigate to the bin file on the server in a browser, can you see it? Does it have the correct MIME type?

Comment: no, I checked with browser on server side. it's ok.

Comment: And we using GPRS :( 56kbit max speed

Comment: Could it be then the connection to the server timing out? Have you simulated downloading the file in chrome? Use dev tools to throttle the connection to GPRS speeds? If not, sorry I don't know.

Comment: Could it be then the connection to the server timing out?  - No
Have you simulated downloading the file in chrome? - Yes

Comment: Use dev tools to throttle the connection to GPRS speeds? - No we will try it thanks